# Sending null without using 0 in WSDL

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, null, wsdl

I have this WSDL content:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SystemName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SystemPassword" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_ZIHUY" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="KOD_CHEVRA" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FAMILY_NAME" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FIRST_NAME" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="KOD_MIN" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="BIRTH_DATE" nillable="true" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SMOKING" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CURRENT_OCCUPATION" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="INTERNET_INDICATOR" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_SOCHEN_MEVUTACH_VIP" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SEMEL_YESHUV" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SHEM_YESHUV" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SEMEL_RECHOV" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SHEM_RECHOV" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_BAIT" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_DIRA" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_KNISA" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OT_BAIT" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MIKUD" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TA_DOAR" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MARITAL_STATUS" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_KIDOMET_TELEFON" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_TELEFON" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_KIDOMET_NAYAD" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_NAYAD" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_KIDOMET_FAX" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MS_FAX" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EMAIL" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="KOD_DIVUR_SHIVUKI" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
 <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="KOD_DIVUR_SHIVUKI_ELC" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
```

but when I want to send null in this fields , i need to send 0  like that :

```
<tem:FAMILY_NAME>0</tem:FAMILY_NAME>
<tem:FIRST_NAME>0</tem:FIRST_NAME>
```

this doesn't help :

```
<tem:FAMILY_NAME/>
<tem:FIRST_NAME/>
```

What should I do if I  want to send null

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to specify them. Don't even write

```
<tem:FAMILY_NAME/>
```

just ignore those param and they will be carried out as default values (null in case of objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
<item:FAMILY_NAME  i:nil="true" />
```

I read this in http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/ at 2.9 Nil Values